# Can't get rid of blank php page after submission form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Were searching for few hours answer on this but I'm completely stacked and brain freezes.

Have subscribe php form with bootstrap modal on successful submission. Everything works, emails passing through, modal showing just after one second or less blank page appear.

I guess that is loaded before form.php file is a separate file but is it there a way to stop loading blank page?

Here is Html code

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <input name="email" class="control-label form-control text-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address ...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>
  </div>
</form> 


<!-- Sart Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
      <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
     </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Thank you</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Thank you for registering, we have added you to the waiting list!
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!--  End Modal -->
```

And here is php code

```html
<?php 
$to = "test@test.com";
$from = "no-reply@test.com";

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

$subject = "New Beta Subscription";
$body = "New user interested in beta program: " . $_POST['email'];


if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{ 
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                window.stop();
                });
                </script>";
    }
   else
    {
       echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
    }
}
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
```

Also want to change Error messages to show up over modals also, that have it generated just not sure if can call two modals from same index file?

Any help is highly welcome!
Thanks, K>

Comment: I think would be better to use php `json_encode` and use `Ajax` on frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve seems different from what you actually coded.

Let's look at your HTML form. You have attached Bootstrap's `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes on your submit button. This means that when you click that button, it will open the modal AND submit the form. So the user will briefly see a modal and see the page redirect to your PHP file. (This is why you are seeing a modal appear briefly.)

Next, let's look at your PHP file. First of all, when you submit a form from one page to another page, that latter page has no idea of the HTML elements in your former page. This means the code you have inside your echo'd `<script>` tag actually should not be working as it is looking for an HTML element on your former page.

Now, for your question as to why are you getting a blank page? Well... everything is working fine so your code echo's a `<script>` tag -- which has no visual indicator. But like I just said, what you have inside the `<script>` does not work -- so nothing shows up and nothing happens.

So recap of the order of events when you click your button: the modal shows up, the form submits, the form redirects to another page, and that other page echo's nothing.

Below is a poor/quick solution to what I think you are trying to achieve:

1. Change your HTML file to a PHP file.
2. Remove `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes off your button, so that it doesn't open the modal right when you click the button

   ```
   <form action="form.php" method="post">
       <div class="form-group label-floating">
           <input name="email" class="control-label form-control text-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address ...">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
3. Move your echo'd `script` tag from your PHP submission page to your PHP form page and wrap it in a condition as shown below:

   ```
   <?php if (!empty($_GET['success'])) : ?>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#myModal").modal();
           });   
       </script>
   <?php endif ?>
   ```
4. Remove your echo'd `script` tag lines of code in your PHP submission page. Instead, add a code so that it redirects back to your PHP form page. The key part is that you will append a `?success=true` at the end of your URL.

   ```
   $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); // valid email or null|false

   if ($email) { 
       $to = "test@test.com";
       $from = "no-reply@test.com";
       $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
       $subject = "New Beta Subscription";
       $body = "New user interested in beta program: " . $email;

       if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)) {
           header('Location: subscribe.php?success=true'); // replace `subscribe.php` with PHP form page
           exit;
       } 
       echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $email . ')';   
   } else {
      echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail'; // no point in printing $email if it is null   
   }
   ```

Basically, passing `?success=true` is for telling the PHP form page that everything went well to open the modal (3).

And that should be it.

A better approach is to learn and use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and step by step guidance. For some reason were not able to make it work... Now I'm getting internal server error instead of that blank page but submitted emails still passing through...

Comment: It might be the `Location: ` string that I forgot to include in the `header()` function.

Comment: Ok, blank page does not appear anymore :) just modal also not appear. Seems like page is refreshed after submission, emails still passing through.

Comment: Assuming you followed the Bootstrap [template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template), you should have included the jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript files at the end of your `body` tag. This means that if you want to add any JavaScript code that relies on both of them, the code has to be placed after them. So make sure (3.) is placed after you include the Bootstrap file. I would also put a `alert('it fired')` in the `document.ready` function of (3.) to see if the code gets into the function. If so, then it's just a problem with showing the modal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Just updated scripts to newer versions and added the script after the linked files!